# Why is my class not being toggled by this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am trying to toggle `.active` class when clicked on the `#datePickerStart` div. It only toggles when i click on the div but I want the element to be hidden when clicked outside of datepicker.

```
$('#datePickerStart').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.path);
    if (!checkEventPathForClass(e.path, 'booking-dropdown')) {
        $('#dropDownStart').classList.toggle('active');
    }
});

function checkEventPathForClass(path, selector) {
    for (item of path) {
        if (item.classList && item.classList.contains(selector)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSBin for my website.](https://jsbin.com/givakacapu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You should declare `item` with `let` or `var`. Also your selector when you're checking the event path should be `'.booking-dropdown'` with a `.` at the beginning.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but the Event object 'path' attribute is non-standard. Use composedPath (method) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare onclick function on entire document and than you can check if clicked Dom is datepicke or just remove active class from datepicker whenever click happens.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if( e.target.id == "dropDonStart" ){
        $('#dropDownStart').classList.toggle('active');
    }else{
        $('#dropDownStart').classList.remove('active');
    }
});
```

Not tested but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function like `shouldToggleClass` and call that function from both the event listener. Also you can  directly use the `click` instead of addEventlistener since jquery is already used

```
const $ = (selector) => {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
};

$('#datePickerStart').addEventListener('click',(e) => {
  shouldToggleClass(e)

});

function shouldToggleClass(e) {
  const isEventPath = checkEventPathForClass(e.path, 'booking-dropdown');
  if (!isEventPath) {
    $('#dropDownStart').classList.toggle('active');
  }
}


function checkEventPathForClass(path, selector) {
  for (item of path) {
    if (item.classList && item.classList.contains(selector)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

$('body').addEventListener('click',(e) => {
  shouldToggleClass(e)
});
```

Comment: jQuery isn't being used. Look at the first 3 lines.

Comment: @GabrielLima apologies for mistake. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the good synthax :

```
`if (!checkEventPathForClass(e.path, 'booking-dropdown')) {
    $('#dropDownStart').classList.add('active');
}`
```

?